# nullpointer exception with amazonhttpclient

Tags: aws-java-sdk

I have put this in sample main class when I execute it I am getting nullpointerexception.it's not giving more details.

My intentions are I am having AWS lambda function which will trigger the above code when any node fails
I am calling a post request in the above code but it's not working
could you please anyone guide me to the write steps or links for this amazonhttpclient related queries.

```
ClientConfiguration configuration = new ClientConfiguration();
    configuration.setMaxErrorRetry(3);
    configuration.setConnectionTimeout(501000);
    configuration.setSocketTimeout(501000);
    configuration.setProtocol(Protocol.HTTP);
            AmazonHttpClient httpClient = new AmazonHttpClient(
                    configuration);
            RequestExecutionBuilder httpRequestBuilder = httpClient.requestExecutionBuilder();
            @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
            String url = "http://localhost:8080/spring4upgrade/processFailureNode"; 
            AmazonWebServiceRequest amazonWebServiceRequest = new AmazonWebServiceRequest() {
            };

            Request paramRequest = new DefaultRequest(amazonWebServiceRequest,"execute-api");
            paramRequest.setEndpoint(URI.create(url));
            paramRequest.setHttpMethod(HttpMethodName.POST);
            paramRequest.addParameter("sgroup", "xyz");
            paramRequest.addParameter("host", "localhost");
            paramRequest.addParameter("port", "8080");
            httpRequestBuilder.request(paramRequest);
            httpRequestBuilder.execute();
```

Comment: are you trying to hit the rest endpoint from lambda or what your are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Before

```
httpRequestBuilder.execute();
```

adding the code below

```
httpRequestBuilder.errorResponseHandler(new ErrorResponseHandler());
```

code for ErrorResponseHandler

```
public class ErrorResponseHandler implements HttpResponseHandler<SdkBaseException> {

    @Override
    public SdkBaseException handle(final HttpResponse response) throws Exception {
        // Do something with response here: status code, response header, ...
        System.out.println("Status Code:");
        System.out.println(response.getStatusCode());
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean needsConnectionLeftOpen() {
        return false;
    }
}
```